# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec

Tags: java, maven, exec

При выполнение команды **mvn exec:exec** выходит ошибка

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ client-ejb ---
Error: Could not find or load main class com.luv2code.client.RemoteEJBClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: client-ejb.com.luv2code.client.RemoteEJBClient
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.584 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-26T11:51:43+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on
project client-ejb: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

Структура проекта :

client-ejb

`--src

   |-- main

        -- java

             -- com

                -- luv2code

                    -- client

                       -- RemoteEJBClient

Код плагина :

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.exec.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/exec-working-directory</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
                                  also adding the project build directory -->
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath />
                        <argument>com.luv2code.client.RemoteEJBClient</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Так ему наверное джарник нужен или хотя бы `.class`-файл, а не исходный код. Проверьте что в вашем класспасе есть чтолибо из указанного.

Comment: @AlexeyR.

есть RenoteEJBClient.class в папке target после mvn install